# Postgres SQL query to find the count of a value from a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a postgres table with the following data:

```
hostname | status
---------+--------
a1       | C
a1       | C
a1       | NC
a2       | NC
a2       | NC
a2       | C
```

I want to display the count of status for C and NC for each hostname, like this:

```
hostname | C total| NC total | Total (C+NC) | C %
---------+--------+----------+--------------+-----
a1       | 2      | 1        | 3            |66.66
a2       | 1      | 2        | 3            |33.33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select hostname,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'C') as num_c,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'NC') as num_nc
from t
group by hostname;
```

For the edit made AFTER I answered, you just follow the same idea:

```
select hostname,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'C') as num_c,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'NC') as num_nc,
       count(*),
       avg( (status = 'C')::int ) as c_ratio
from t
group by hostname;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the C% as well like this: `hostname | C total| NC total | Total (C+NC) | C %
---------+--------+----------+--------------+-----
a1       | 2      | 1        | 3            |66.66
a2       | 1      | 2        | 3            |33.33`